# when I should call jenkins build after git commit or git push?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am working on a building a website. and I want to write an automated jenkins pipeline which will make changes in production environment. What are the best practices to push the code to production and when should i trigger a build after commit or push ?

Comment: Commits usually are done quite often; so it makes sense to trigger build after push, not commit.

Comment: I agree with @kosist. After a commit there is no new source code on the remote (github/ gitlab/ bitbucket) so jenkins cannot test/build something new.